# Dynamics CRM 2011 - entering dollar amounts in a dialog - using float

Tags: dialog, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, microsoft-dynamics

We use dialogs to enter fine amounts in dollars.

In the CRM dialog, the option to enter a floating point in a prompt and response has only 
Text, integer and float.

If we choose float, the number defaults to 5 decimal places. so if someone enters $150.00 , the system immediately changes to 150.00000  which completely throws people off.

We cant use integers. Any way to set the precision to 2, or to at least not tack on zeroes in a dialog?

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more. Are you using javascript dialogs ??

Answer (score 2):

Dialog processes are limited in the extent their layout and behaviour can be customized. The number of decimals of floats can not be modified for dialog processes.

Comment: Where is this setting? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: I overlooked you were referring to dialog processes, sorry for this. Dialog processes are very limited when it comes to customizing their behaviour. The number of decimals of floats can not be modified for dialog processes. I modified my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunately not standard out of the box functionality of Dynamics CRM in dialogs, however you may be able to look into writing a plugin to give the desired dialog which includes validation of the field you want to act as currency.